# How can I manually generate a new temporary ipv6 address by generating a new host identifier on Windows/Linux

Tags: linux, windows, ipv6, privacy-extensions

Right now I am playing a bit with IPv6. Is there any way how I can manually force Windows/Linux to generate a new host identifier instead of waiting for Windows/Linux to do it on it's on schedule through the IPv6 privacy extension.

Comment: @Ramhound: They do. The question isn't about DHCP (v4 nor v6), but about IPv6 [stateless autoconfiguration](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4862), in which the router just advertises a /64 and the host chooses its own address. [Temporary addresses](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4941) are an extension of that.

Comment: @Ramhound: the [tag:privacy-extensions] is pretty clear now.

Comment: @Ramhound: he explicitly mentions Privacy Extensions, so it is definitely not about DHCP or the ISP uplink, but about autoconf.

Comment: @Ramhound: ack. Before that he was asking about temporary addresses, which indeed could theoretically also be about IA_TA :)

Answer (score 2):

I have just tried to see if I could get a Linux kernel to generate new temporary addresses, and I couldn't find something that works. Switching `use_tempaddr` off and on on the interface makes you lose the existing addresses but it doesn't generate new ones until the next RA comes in.

My best guess at the moment is that there is no good way to make Linux do what you ask. I don't know about Windows. I don't have a test box to experiment with at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 7, disabling and reenabling the network adapter results in a newly generated temporary IPv6 address.

```
netsh interface set interface name="nameofyourinterface" admin=disabled
netsh interface set interface name="nameofyourinterface" admin=enabled
```